# How to display images stored in array with next and prev hyperlink?

Tags: php

I am returning images from a database and store them in PHP array. The images can be 2 or 3 depends on the result set. So, now I have PHP array of images. I am able to show them on a page. The problem is I want to show one image at a time. Second, I want to make next and prev hyperlink to move across. I've tried several times, looked out for answers but couldn't succeed.

Here is my code:

```
$query="SELECT letterNo, height, path from imageTable where letterNo=".$letterNumber;

$rs=mysql_query($query,$connection);
$totalRows=mysql_num_rows($rs);
$myArray[ ] = array();
$image[ ]=array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRows; ++$i)
{
    $myArray[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $image[$i]='<img src="' .$myArray[$i]['path'].'.jpg"' .' width="630" height="'.$myArray[$i] ['height'].'" alt=Letter "'.$letterNumber.'" />';
}
for($i=0;$i<$totalRows;$i++)
{
print $image[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to fetch the id's of the links of your images and navigate around your database; previous gets the image before the current image out of the database, and next gets the next one (if there is one).
You just need a way to store the index or the databaseinformation somehow

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am returning images in a result set. Then store all images in PHP. so the result becomes $image[0th image][1st image][2nd image]..Now I want to move through images using next and prev hyperlink but on the same page.

Comment: $query="SELECT letterNo, width, height, path from annimages where letterNo=".$letterNumber;

$rs=mysql_query($query,$connection);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
 echo '<br/>';
echo '<img src="' .$row['path'].'.jpg"' .' width="'.$row['width'].'" height="'.$row['height'].'" alt=Letter "'.$letterNumber.'" />'. '<br/>';
}